# Android java set number of decimals

Tags: java, android, double, rounding

I've a variable price which is defined this way:

```
   double price;
   price = 7.6;
```

Up to here everything is right. The problem is that when I make this:

```
   price = 7.6 * 3;
```

What i get is

```
   price = 22.799999999999999999999999997
```

instead of

```
   price = 22.80
```

which is what i need.

Any ideas about how to solve this??  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `BigDecimal` or store your amounts of money in cents and use `long`.

For reasons read [Effective Java Item 48](http://books.google.de/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&lpg=PP1&hl=de&pg=PA215#v=onepage&q&f=false).

In summary:
Don't use `double` and `float` when you need exact values. These datatypes cannot represent numbers wich are a negative power of ten. (e.g. 0.1)
Use `BigDecimal` instead. For monetary values `long` or `int` are more suitable in most cases.

Your example using long:

```
long price; //store values in euro cents
price = 760 * 3; //price is now 2280 cents
```

Comment: Y need to store it on euros, if possible.

Comment: Then use `BigDecimal` or convert your euros to euro cents and use `long`/`int`. `double` and `float` are for scientific calcs.

Comment: @user1098933 `BigDecimal.valueOf(price, 2).toPlainString()` You may want to have a look at [Joda Money](http://joda-money.sourceforge.net/) lib.

Answer (score 3):

Never use floating point (double or float) to sore currency values, as floating point values are by definition approximations. You should either store values in an int/long (e.g. $ cents rather than dollars), or use a class specifically designed for currencies.

There's more information and detail here:
http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=13

Comment: Could you post an example? I've been looking on the net but i find it too complicated. Thanks